# Javascript mapping

Tags: javascript, arrays

In our project we are getting below data from DB in following format.

```
[
    [
        "ClearDB",
        "test1@test.com",
        "com.test.cleardb"
    ],
    [
        "Cricbuzz",
        "test2@test.com",
        "com.test.cricbuzz"
    ],
    [
        "Hangout",
        "test3@test.com",
        "com.test.hangout"
    ]
]
```

I want this in key value format as mentioned below

```
[
    {
        "projname": "ClearDB",
        "projmanager": "test1@test.com",
        "package": "com.test.cleardb"
    },
    {
        "projname": "Cricbuzz",
        "projmanager": "test2@test.com",
        "package": "com.test.cricbuzz"
    },
    {
        "projname": "Hangout",
        "projmanager": "test3@test.com",
        "package": "com.test.hangout"
    }
]
```

Please provide me a proper way to implement this.

Comment: please be advised SO is *not* a "get my work done for free" site, maybe next time you should at least show us what you've tried so far, instead of saying "i have X, i want Y, please do it for me."

Comment: downvoted for research effort, and nothing provided from OP about what he tried. (5 upvotes .. how can users like OP understand that this is not a good question with so many upvote)

Comment: Downvoted for the same reason. At least show an attempt at resolving the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply create a new object for each of the arrays, and create an array of objects with `map` function, like this

```
var keys = ["projname", "projmanager", "package"];

console.log(data.map(function (arr) {
  var obj = {};
  keys.forEach(function (key, idx) { obj[key] = arr[idx]; });
  return obj;
}));
```

**Output**

```
[ { projname: 'ClearDB',
    projmanager: 'test1@test.com',
    package: 'com.test.cleardb' },
  { projname: 'Cricbuzz',
    projmanager: 'test2@test.com',
    package: 'com.test.cricbuzz' },
  { projname: 'Hangout',
    projmanager: 'test3@test.com',
    package: 'com.test.hangout' } ]
```

Answer (score 4):

with `Array.prototype.map`:

```
var results = db.map(function (v) {
  return {
     projname: v[0],
     projmanager: v[1],
     package: v[2]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if

```
var array =[
[
    "ClearDB",
    "test1@test.com",
    "com.test.cleardb"
],
[
    "Cricbuzz",
    "test2@test.com",
    "com.test.cricbuzz"
],
[
    "Hangout",
    "test3@test.com",
    "com.test.hangout"
]
];
```

then

```
var obj = [];
array.each(function(item){ obj.push({"projname": item[0],
                                      "projmanager":item[1], 
                                      "package": item[2]})
});
```

**Edit:**

Using Jquery

```
var obj = [];
$.each(array,function(key,value){ obj.push({"projname": value[0],
                                      "projmanager":value[1], 
                                      "package": value[2]})
});
```

Using javascript

```
var obj = [];
array.forEach(function(item){ obj.push({"projname": item[0],
                                      "projmanager":item[1], 
                                      "package": item[2]})
});
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.each` doesn't exists, it's `forEach`

Comment: Sorry i thought you are using jquery to, if not yes use forEach. Thanks @Arnaud Gueras

Comment: Even if the developer uses jQuery, the `.each()` method is not avalaible on Array object. It's available only on jQuery collection of via `$.each(myArray,...)`

Comment: may be `$(array).each(...)`? But even with this you'll get `(index, item)` arguments

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the data you are getting from database is stored in variable 'abc'

```
var abc = [];
var output = [];
for(var i = 0; i< abc.length; i++){
    output[i] = {};
    output[i].projname = abc[i][0];
    output[i].projmanager = abc[i][1];
    output[i].package = abc[i][2];
}
```

Note: 'abc' is the variable where you are storing data from DB.

Comment: Sure, this works, but why would you use four lines to initialize and fill in the object one property at a time, instead of just saying `output[i] = {projname: abc[i][0], ...` etc.?

Comment: Its simpler for others to understand. not everyone is skillfull

Comment: Writing a simple object literal does not fall into the "skillful" category, it falls into the "extremely basic" category.

Answer (score 1):

In ES6:

```
input . map(([projname, projmanager, package]) => ({projname, projmanager, package}));
```

The part in `[]` deconstructs the parameter to `map`, which is one of the subarrays, assigning the first element to `projname`, and so on. The part in `{}` creates and returns an object with a key of `'projname'` whose value is `projname`, etc.

If you want to generalize this to use any array of field names (`['projname', 'projmanager', 'package']`):

```
input . map(
  values => 
    values . reduce(
      (result, value, i) => {
        result[fieldnames[i]] = value;
        return result;
      },
      {}
    )
);
```